# save file in media folder on server django

Tags: python, django, file, pdf, path

so i´ve created a pdf document which should be saved in media/postings. the path is already in the function, but the pdf is not saved there but in the main project folder. what did i overlook here?

a little explanation for the def: the post is created and uploaded to the feed, while the image in the post is renamed and put into another folder. Also, a pdf is created, containing the posted material. How do i determine where this pdf goes on the server? i thought it is solved with the path_name and path_file but it doesn't work. thanks in advance.

```
def post_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostCreateForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.cleaned_data['num_post'] = Post.objects.count() + 1
            Post.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
    else:
        form = PostCreateForm()

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})



def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        image = request.FILES.get('image_upload')
        caption = request.POST['caption']
        num_post = Post.objects.count()+1
        new_post = Post.objects.create(image=image, caption=caption, num_post=num_post)
        new_post.save()



        #create pdf
        buffer = io.BytesIO()

        x_start = 100
        y_start = 10

        folder_path = f"media/postings/post{num_post}.pdf"
        folder_name = os.path.basename(folder_path)
        print(folder_path)
        p = canvas.Canvas(folder_name, pagesize=A4,)
        #p == request.FILES.get('postings')

        p.drawImage(ImageReader(image.file), x_start, y_start, width=420, preserveAspectRatio=True, mask='auto')
        p.drawString(150, 650, new_post.caption)
        p.drawString(100, 650, "caption:")
        p.drawString(100, 170, str(new_post.created_at))
        p.drawString(200, 700, str(num_post))
        p.drawString(100, 700, "post no.:")
        p.drawString(250, 700, "//")
        p.drawString(100, 690, "===========================================================")
        p.drawString(300, 700, str(new_post.id))
        #p.showPage()
        p.save()


        buffer.seek(0)
        #return render(request, '/', {'folder_name': folder_name, })
        return redirect('/'), folder_path

    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

```
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    num_post = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=post_images)
    caption = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    number_of_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    like_list = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    #likes_row = models.TextField(max_length=1000, default="hi")
    number_of_dislikes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    interaction_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    #downloads = models.FileField(upload_to='postings', blank=True, null=True)


    @property
    def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.image.name).split('.')[0]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.caption
```

Answer (score 1):

os.path.basename returns only the right part of the path "postxxx.pdf" in your code and this is handed over to canvas...

```
folder_path = f"media/postings/post{num_post}.pdf"
folder_name = os.path.basename(folder_path)
        
p = canvas.Canvas(folder_name, pagesize=A4,)
```